# Redux-Saga generator function return nested json object which isn't I want

Tags: unit-testing, nested, generator, jestjs, redux-saga

When I use `call` to fetch api, it should be return just a string. But it returns a JSON object.

EX:

- when I call `const product = yield call(api.fetchProductAPI);`
- I expect to be  `const product = "iphone";`
- but it will be  `const product = { product: 'iphone' };`

Does anyone know what is going on about this? Thanks.

=====================

Check the code below

https://gist.github.com/Hsueh-Jen/f1459d19dfe01c525cbb55c8426e410e

and error message below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmRPC.png

Comment: I think it's an error in you test. This line: `expect(gen.next({ product }).value).toEqual(put({ type: 'PRODUCTS_RECEIVED', product: 'iphone' }));` should be `expect(gen.next(product).value).toEqual(put({ type: 'PRODUCTS_RECEIVED', product: 'iphone' }));`

Comment: That's true. How silly I am. Thanks so much. Don't you use "Answer" so that I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an error in you test. This line:

```
expect(gen.next({ product }).value).toEqual(put({ type: 'PRODUCTS_RECEIVED', product: 'iphone' }));
```

should be

```
expect(gen.next(product).value).toEqual(put({ type: 'PRODUCTS_RECEIVED', product: 'iphone' }));
```